# Render an attributes of each object - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view right now that renders an object on the page. The object is an `Integration`. On the `Integration` object I have attribute called `filters`. `Filters` are stored as an array. All I need to do is list out the filters of each integration below them in a list. Here is my code.

### View

```
 <% if @integrations.any? %>
  <div class="configured-integrations">
    <h3 class="heading-3">My Configured Integrations:</h3>

    <ul class="integration-list integration-list--compact">
      <%= render @integrations %>
    </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

### Screenshot

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that each of those elements are integrations. I need to list the filters of each integration below the title there.

### Controller

```
 def index
    # Get the list of the user's integrations grouped first by provider then
    # from oldest to newest."
    @integrations = current_account.integrations
      .order(type: :asc, created_at: :asc)
 end
```

I hope this is clear enough. So recap: I need to list the filters on each integration below. I've already tried stuff like this `@integrations.first.filters` but that wont work because it's a static call. I need something like a list. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another partial to render all filters which are associated with your Integration.

Create a partial file *_show_filters.html.erb* in your views

```
    <% filters.each do |filter| %>
      <li><%= filter %></li>          
    <% end %>
```

And render this partial while iterating through your @integration object like this.

```
<% if @integrations.any? %>
   <div class="configured-integrations">
     <h3 class="heading-3">My Configured Integrations:</h3>
     <ul class="integration-list integration-list--compact">
       <% @integrations.each do |integration| %>
          <li>
            <%= integration %>
            <ul class="">
              <%= render 'show_filters', filters: integration.filters %>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to iterate through each integration, then `<%= render integeration.filters %>`

```
 <% if @integrations.any? %>
   <div class="configured-integrations">
     <h3 class="heading-3">My Configured Integrations:</h3>

     <ul class="integration-list integration-list--compact">
       <% @integrations.each do |integration| %>
          <li>
            <%= integration %>
            <ul class="">
              <%= render integration.filters %>
            </ul>
          </li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

You will have to update this code to make the partials work, but i hope this gets the idea across.

You can't use the shortcut `<%= render @integrations %>` here, because you want a subgroup inside `@integrations`. So you'll have to do it the long way.

Comment: I think you're right but I get this error now `"It"' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Comment: `:to_partial_path` tells Rails which partial to render, so the error may mean it is confused which partial to render. I'm confused what `It"` is? Maybe you can try use to `.each` on the filters as well?